# How do I disable column sorting in jQuery Grid plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I would like to disable sorting, and enable altRows in jQuery Grid plugin. Here's my clientside code:

```
var myGrid = $("#list").jqGrid({
    url: '/Home/GetData/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['Id', 'Description'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', width: 40 },
        { name: 'Description', width: 400}],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    sortable: false,
    altRows: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'My first grid'
});
```

My server-side controller action signature is:

```
public ActionResult GetData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
```

So far sorting is still enabled, and there's no altRows highlighting. I'm sure it's something terribly obvious that I missed but can't for the life of me figured out what.

Any ideas please?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your column model, set each column's `sortable` to false.

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'Id', width: 40, sortable: false },
    { name: 'Description', width: 400, sortable: false }]
```

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options

For alternating rows, look at `altRows` and `altclass` property options on the grid:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: Thank you - in that case I made at least two mistakes. I put the sortable property in the wrong place, and was missing the altclass property. It's all working great now.

Answer (score 0):

find Sort in the js turn it to false

```
Sort: false
```